# How to figure out where a number is located in a matrix and delete it as well as add it?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that is a bunch of rows, e.g:

```
x = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

What I am trying to do is add `3.5` in the matrix while maintaining the order. For instance, the above matrix would be:

```
[1; 2; 3; 3.5; 4; 5]
```

The other thing I wanted to figure out is how to check if a number exists in a matrix within a certain interval. For instances, if I want to see if `4.5` exists within a `.5` interval, it would say that it is found at `4` and `5`.

I can see doing this by doing a `for` loop, but this feels like something MATLAB should have done built in. The reason I want this is to make my code efficient because I will be handling a huge data set. For the interval problem, I was thinking of using `ismembertol`, but the problem with that is tol is always a percentage, it isn't a hard-coded number like `.5`.

Comment: You can use find() function to  locate the number in your matrix, for the first question just add or remove an element then use sort() function to rank  the array  from smallest to largest number

Comment: @Adam You don't even need the `sort` function. If you find the locations of the neighbors of the number, you know where to insert that number.

Answer (score 0):

```
%assume that it is in sorted order
insertind = find(x<3.5,1, 'last') 
x = [x(1:insertind); 3.5; x(insertind+1:end)]; %inserted at that index
%exists within tolerance
find(abs(x-4.5)<=0.5)
```